# SlidingUpPanelLayout with gravity=top wont snap in at bottom

Tags: android

The question is about `com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout`.
I used the layout with the `gravity=top` to make the slidingPanel apear at the top of the main context.

But now the `slidingPanel` does not snap in, when it is moved to the bottom. 
It immediately goes returns to the top. 
It only snaps in when I drag it a little bit down and then release it.

Seems like the panel has an offset after which it snaps in, which is measured from the bottom. 
Event if the `slidingPanel` is at the top.

Do someone know how to repair that?

[image]
[image]

Comment: try using the `paralaxOffset`

Comment: how do you use the attribute paralaxOffset? There is no documentation about it

Comment: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel see it under

Comment: yeah, I found that  it says `You can add paralax to the main view by setting paralaxOffset attribute (see demo for the example).` But what is parallax and how does it help me in my case? I added `paralaxOffset =100dp` and I added `paralaxOffset=-100dp`but I could not see any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the behaviour I described is with the min. velocity which is required to detect a fling.

Set `DEFAULT_MIN_FLING_VELOCITY=0` to make the Sliding Panel expand, after user releases it on any height.